# How do you limit the number of characters used for that username for java android?

Tags: java, android, xml, size, limit

When adding value to a username in an Android app, how do you limit the number of characters used for that username?

Comment: try this : `editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(15)});`

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:maxLength` in xml

Example Code:

```
<EditText
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:maxLength="20"/>
```